# How can I show the same data in two different sheet tabs in a way that when you change the data in one of the tabs it will change in the another?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

How can I show the same data in two different sheet tabs in a way that when you change the data in one of the tabs it will change in the another?

I know how to import same data to different tabs.
The point here that I want both of the tab to have the abbility to change the data in a way that the change will be shown in both of the tabs.

(Im using Google sheets)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in your Sheet2 use:

```
={Sheet1!A1:Z}
```

this way if you change anything in Sheet1 it will be reflected in Sheet2

changes in Sheet2 are not possible to be reflected back into Sheet1 ofc

Comment: Thanks,
This one I know, I need to be able to change the data through Sheet2 as well.

Comment: @TzahPerry as stated in the answer such functionality is not supported by google sheets coz it would create a paradox